# Получить элементы торгового каталога по цене, не выше указанной

Tags: php, битрикс

Пытаюсь получить элементы инфоблока, я являющегося торговым каталогом, по цене, не превышающей указанную в условии. Почему-то выдает все элементы.

```php
if (CModule::IncludeModule("iblock")) {
    $arSelect = array("ID", "NAME", "IBLOCK_ID", "CATALOG_CATALOG_GROUP_ID_1");
    $arFilter = array("IBLOCK_ID" => 4, "ACTIVE" => "Y", "CATALOG_PRICE_1" <= 500);

    $el_tree = array();

    $res = CIBlockElement::GetList(array("SORT" => "DESC"), $arFilter, false, false, $arSelect);
    while ($ob_arr = $res->Fetch()) {
        $el_tree[$ob_arr['NAME']] = $ob_arr;
    }

    foreach ($el_tree as $el_NAME => $el) {
        echo 'NAME: ', $el_NAME, ' is <pre>', print_r($el), '</pre>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Неправильно написано условия для цены, в частности, больше-равно ставится перед названием параметра.
Вот правильная стройка условия:

```
$arFilter = array("IBLOCK_ID" => 4, "ACTIVE" => "Y", "<=CATALOG_PRICE_1" => 500);
```